# How to trigger mysql event after a time period?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database that stores users that are online. Is there an efficient way of triggering an event after a time period to detect the users that are inactive (to set their status to "offline")? I'm storing the last time the user was active in a table (TIMESTAMP value).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a cron job to call a PHP script to update the users table.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a php script regularly, you have many solutions :

- You use a cron job (this implies that you have a server). For learn to do this you can [visit this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/).
- You use the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) provided by MySQL.
- If you not have server, you can use a provider who will launch your tasks regularly, the most known is [Webcron.org](http://webcron.org/) (it's not free).
- Other solution, you create a script PHP that will run in the background while waiting for the right time to perform an action ; for do that you must have access to function `set_time_limit()` and `ignore_user_abort()`. Then you create a script that loops continuously and checks for the moment whether there is something to do.