# PHP $run AFTER $time

Tags: php, mysqli

I need something that will help me achieve this:

I run a code eg: `$v = 2;`, after I run it I want it to wait 5 minutes and run `$v = 3;`

The thing is that I want that to happen in the background so `sleep();` won't work. :(

Help pleaase.

EG (PHP):

```
if(isset($_POST['finish'])){
    $eventid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);

    if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE events SET status = '2'  WHERE id = '" . $eventid . "'")) {
        $successmsg = "Saved!";
```

WAIT 5 MINUTES

```
        if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE events SET status = '3'  WHERE id = '" . $eventid . "'")) {
            $successmsg = "5 Mins Gone";
        } else {
            $errormsg = "5 Mins Error";
        }
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: cron job? spawn a child process with sleep?

Comment: @Dagon More like a timer. Eg. When a button is pressed wait $t time and UPDATE table

Comment: you could update immediately but add a time stamp that could be checked as well

Comment: @Dagon Ok, so say I add a timestamp. How would it know that 5 minutes had passed. I mean what will I use to check the timestamp?

Comment: i would assume you query the table at some point? noting in your original code shows any db operations ,so your not making it easy to help you

Comment: @dagon posted PHP code example in question

Answer (score -1):

PHP only life when send action or load the page, so with php you can't do this.

You need to use javascript or Cronjob for it :)

Node.js is rly nice option for you to build life program.

Or you can do seperate programm with C++ or other languages.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how would I do it with javascript?

Comment: it gives multiple choices, i need know what your plan is. Must it be safe?

Comment: @ivorysmoker After a button is pressed "Status" column in the DataBase is UPDATED to 1. Then I need the code to wait 5 minutes and UPDATE status to 2. This should be done in the backgorund. Eg. if the tab is closed it should still be updated in the given time.

Comment: @Dragon with Node.js and database. And php interfaced to the same database.

Comment: Ah, if u do this only in background then u cant use javascript. For javascript the User need connected to the site. Then you need use Cronjob. With Cronjob i cant help you.  Or maybe you can do with MySQL. More Information you find in this thread. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822217/how-to-trigger-mysql-event-after-a-time-period)

Comment: @Dragon true story! Node.js is great for that. With Node.js u have life programm ;)

Comment: @Dragon, you can build Node.js with javascript ;) So if you have much time you can do alot with it. *smile*